# Dojo JS ToggleButton show as enabled but disallow click/toggle and hover outline

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, togglebutton

I need to use a ToggleButton to show an image and some text and I want the button to appear enabled (colored icon and black text), but I do not want to allow click/toggle to happen right now as this functionality will come later. Again I need the icon colored and the text black but the button to not be clickable (basically should look not like a button, no outline when hover, etc).

```
this.button = new ToggleButton({
                         "id": title,
                         "label": count,
                         "showLabel": true,
                         "iconClass": "eIcon",
                         "class": "buttonText",
                         "disabled": true,
                 });
```

I cannot get the CSS to work properly - I tried to put the color for the button in the CSS like this:

```
.itpButtonText { color: black !important; }
```

But it never gets picked up. Maybe i need to do the reverse, allow it to be enabled, but then not allow hover or to be clicked?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, are there any particular reason you need use ToggleButton to implement this? Actually, it is easy to use two divs (one for img class, another for text)  to implement the same effect you want to achieve, you just need keep a status and based on this status, style them accordingly.

If you still need use toggleButton, you can try overwrite some default styles of ToggleButton  for your particular button. Use inspector to get corresponding class name you need change,  search them in your theme css file, then overrite them in your own css file.

for example, to overwrite hover behaviors, you may need overwrit

```
.claro .dijitToggleButtonHover .dijitButtonNode {
  background-color: #86bdf2;
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

with

```
.yourClass .claro  .dijitToggleButtonHover .dijitButtonNode {
   /* your styles */

}
```

But you may need do a lot of this kind of overwrite, so maybe it is better to create a customize button using the first method.